# Construct a pentagon avoiding compass use

Tags: math, geometry, atomic-code-golf

### Rules

You will start with only two elements: Points \$A\$ and \$B\$ such that \$A \neq B\$.  These points occupy a plane that is infinite in all directions.

At any step in the process you may do any of the three following actions:

1. Draw a line that passes through two points.
2. Draw a circle centered at one point such that another point lies on the circle.
3. Add a new point where two objects (lines and circles) intersect.

Your goal is to create 5 points such that they form the vertices of a [regular pentagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Regular_pentagons) (a convex polygon with 5 sides equal in length) using as few circles as possible.  You may, of course, have other points but 5 of them must for a regular pentagon.  You do not have to draw the edges of the pentagon for your scoring.

### Scoring

When comparing two answers the one that draws fewer circles is better.  In the case of a tie in circles the answer that draws the fewest lines is better.  In the case of a tie in both circles and lines the answer that adds the fewest points is better.

### Anti-Rules

*While the rules list is exhaustive and details everything you can do, this list is not. Just because I don't say you can't do something does not mean you can.*

- You cannot create "arbitrary" objects.  Some constructions you will find will do things like add a point at an "arbitrary" location and work from there.  You cannot add new points at locations other than intersections.
- You cannot copy a radius.  Some constructions will involve taking a compass setting it to a radius between two points and then picking it up and drawing a circle elsewhere.  You cannot do this.
- You cannot perform limiting processes.  All constructions must take a finite number of steps.  It is not good enough to approach the answer asymptotically.
- You cannot draw an arc or part of a circle in order to avoid counting it as a circle in your scoring.  If you want to visually use arcs when showing or explaining your answer because they take up less space go ahead but they count as a circle for scoring.

### Tools

You can think through the problem on [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing).  Just go over to the shapes tab.  The three rules are equivalent to the point, line and circle with center tools.

### Burden of Proof

This is standard but I would like to reiterate.  If there is a question as to whether a particular answer is valid the burden of proof is on the answerer to show that their answer is valid rather than the public to show that the answer is not.

### What is this doing on my Code-Golf site?!

This is a form of [atomic-code-golf](/questions/tagged/atomic-code-golf) similar to [proof-golf](/questions/tagged/proof-golf) albeit in a bit of a weird programming language. There is currently [a +22/-0 consensus on the meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16689/56656) that this sort of thing is allowed.

Comment: This is like the game I have on my phone called Euclidea.

Comment: closely related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/38653/15599

Comment: "setting it two a radius" a likely typo

Comment: Next time you should ask people to draw a heptagon, which would be slightly more challenging:)

Comment: @flawr "Slightly", hmm?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a 13-gon is possible, so that would be quite challenging.

Comment: It's the regular 17-gon which is constructible using ruler and compasses. I can give you a heptagon but it won't necessarily be regular!

Comment: Heptagon (7 sides) is not possible with only ruler and compass. [Mathologer covered it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1sPvUr0YC0).

Comment: If the 17-gon is too easy, there's always the regular 65537-gon...

Comment: Are answers supposed to actually prove/explain why the resulting pentagon is regular? It's not obvious to me just by following the construction.

Comment: @Minethlos Answers don't have to prove there correctness by default but the burden of proof is on the answerer.  If don't follow why an answer should be regular just leave a comment asking for clarification.

Answer (score 46):

## 2 circles, 13 lines, 17 points

[image: picture]

[Try it on GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/geometry/c4ttfqt6)

- Let circle(A, B) intersect circle(B, A) at C and D.
- Let AB intersect circle(A, B) again at E.
- Let AB intersect circle(B, A) again at F.
- Let AD intersect circle(A, B) again at G.
- Let AD intersect CF at H.
- Let BG intersect DF at I.
- Let HI intersect circle(A, B) at J and K.
- Let BG intersect EJ at L.
- Let BJ intersect EG at M.
- Let BG intersect EK at N.
- Let BK intersect EG at O.
- Let LM intersect circle(A, B) at P and S.
- Let NO intersect circle(A, B) at Q and R.

Then EPQRS is a regular pentagon.

#### Why it works

Let BE intersect GJ at T, and let BE intersect GK at U.  The complete quadrilateral BEGJ shows that T is the [polar](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polar.html) of LM, which is the intersection of the tangents at P and S.  Similarly, the complete quadrilateral BEGK shows that U is the polar of NO, which is the intersection of the tangents at Q and R.

Let FG intersect HI at V.  The diagonals DV and GI of the complete quadrilateral DGVI intersect FH at [harmonic conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate) with respect to F and H; since the first is at ∞, the second is the midpoint C of FH, which is to say that C, D, V are collinear.

Let CG intersect HI at W.

[image: picture]

Now for the fun part.  Line FUBAT is [perspective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspectivity) about G to line VKIHJ, which is perspective about D to circle CKDGJ, which is perspective about C to line HKVWJ, which is perspective about G to line AUF∞T.  Composing these four perspecitivities yields a [projectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectivity) FUBAT ⌅ AUF∞T.  Since a one-dimensional projectivity is determined by three points, T and U are determined as the two fixed points of FBA ⌅ AF∞.

Assigning coordinates with A = 0, B = −1, F = −2, this projectivity is defined by *x* ↦ 4/*x* + 2, and its fixed points T = 1 + √5 = sec(2π/5) and U = 1 − √5 = −sec(2π/10), exactly as required to make EPQRS a regular pentagon.

Comment: How did you find this? Looks amazing.

Comment: How do you draw the third line? This seems like a perpendicular bisector, but how do you draw this without drawing circles? The same goes for the fourth line, and many more.

Comment: Please explain each step of your algorithm in words and symbols.

Comment: @Servaes This answer could use some explanation, but I can tell you that the third line is fine, it is a perpendicular bisector but it is defined in terms of two preexisting points rather than as a perpendicular bisector.  Same goes for the fourth one.

Comment: @RosieF Sorry about that, the labels were annoying to add with the way I had been producing the pictures. I redid this in GeoGebra with labelled points and added instructions and a link to the interactive app where you can play with the construction.

Comment: Looks like a neat solution, but do you care to explain why the result is a regular pentagon? I.e. why EP = PQ = QR = RS = SE?

Comment: @Minethlos It took a while to come up with a nice proof but I finally found one that I’m happy with. Be warned that it requires a fair amount of background in projective geometry.

Comment: Move over FOOBAR, we now have FUBAT

Answer (score 17):

## <s>7</s> 6 circles, 3 lines

This is a classical pentagon construction, a proof of its correctness can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95614/109451).

[image]

Answer (score 13):

## 4 circles, 7 lines

Since it has been beaten I thought I would just post my original solution to the problem.  This solution is modified from the method given by Dixon in *Mathographics*, a proof of correctness for that method can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95614/276060).

- Draw \$\mathrm{Circle}(A,B)\$
- Draw \$\overline{AB}\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(A,B)\$ and \$\overline{AB}\$ as \$C\$
- Draw \$\mathrm{Circle}(B,C)\$
- Draw \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\mathrm{Circle}(B,C)\$ as \$D\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\overline{AB}\$ as \$E\$
- Draw \$\overline{DC}\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\overline{DC}\$ as \$F\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\mathrm{Circle}(B,C)\$ as \$G\$
- Draw \$\overline{BG}\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\overline{BG}\$ and \$\overline{EF}\$ as \$H\$
- Draw \$\overline{HC}\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\overline{HC}\$ and \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ as \$I\$
- Draw \$\overline{IA}\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\overline{IA}\$ and \$\mathrm{Circle}(A,B)\$ as \$J\$
- Draw \$\mathrm{Cirlce}(I,J)\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(I,J)\$ and \$\overline{HC}\$ as \$L\$
- Mark the intersections of \$\mathrm{Circle}(I,J)\$ and \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ as \$M\$ and \$K\$.
- Draw \$\overline{ML}\$
- Draw \$\overline{KL}\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\overline{ML}\$ as \$N\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\overline{HC}\$ as \$O\$
- Mark the intersection of \$\mathrm{Circle}(C,B)\$ and \$\overline{KL}\$ as \$P\$

\$MKPON\$ is a regular pentagon.

[image: Drawing]

Comment: This is marvellous! Some of your construction resembles Dixon's method, but your method cleverly avoids bisecting anything or constructing a perpendicular.

Comment: @RosieF It is modified from Dixon's method, I probably should have mentioned that.